# com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

Tags: json

Java class:

```
import com.google.gson.Gson;
import com.google.gson.GsonBuilder;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class Json {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //JSONObject jObject = new JSONObject();
        //Json json=new  Json();
        ArrayList al = new ArrayList();
        al.add(1);
        al.add("Lokesh");
        al.add("Gupta");
        al.add(Arrays.asList("ADMIN", "MANAGER"));
        Gson gson = new Gson();
        String st = gson.toJson(al);
        Gson gs = new GsonBuilder().create();
        Json json = gs.fromJson(st, Json.class);
        System.out.println(json.toString());
    }
}
```

> error:com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_ARRAY but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2

Comment: Can you show the content of the String `st`?

Comment: [1,"Lokesh","Gupta",["ADMIN","MANAGER"]]

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem is on that line:

```
Json json = gs.fromJson(st, Json.class);
```

The `Json` class is not a collection, that's why Gson cannot deserialize it. Although indeed the error message is far from explicit.

I suggest you try the following instead:

either

```
Object[] objects = gs.fromJson(st, Object[].class);
```

or

```
Type collectionType = new TypeToken<Collection<Object>>(){}.getType();
Collection<Object> objects = gs.fromJson(st, collectionType);
```

(adapted from the Gson user guide: https://sites.google.com/site/gson/gson-user-guide#TOC-Collections-Examples)

Comment: @KRISHJIRAO That sounds like you're returning the object, not its contents.

Comment: kk but i need..l,lokesg gupta ,admin, manager..How to write program? how to modify this program?

Comment: tanq verymuch @ cardian

Comment: @KRISHJIRAO - thank me by up-voting and accepting the answer ;-)

Comment: String st = gson.toJson(al);                                                              ArrayList a2= gson.fromJson(st, ArrayList.class);
       System.out.println(a2);